# Problema con Server Tomcat

Tags: java, struts

Hola amigos estoy comenzando a programar con Eclipse Oxigen , y  tengo este error de Tomcat , desearia que me ayudara porque no puedo levantar el proyecto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Kevin, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Ese error puede ser por muuuchos motivos ( por ejemplo, me pasó el otro dia por no tener la VPN conectada) . Si no proporcionas más información no será reprodible el error y cerrada la pregunta. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: Añade los detalles, y el log del servidor. Este mensaje solo dice que no se pudo arrancar el tomcat, no explica el porqué.

Comment: me pudieran dar opciones porque no lo levanta , estado mirando videos en youtube y la verdad que no se porque tengo este problema , sera porque el puerto que usa java esta ocupado.

Comment: @SJuan76 El por qué está ahí escrito: Eclipse canceló la ejecución porque consideró que estaba tardando demasiado en arrancar

Answer (score -1):

Cuando lanzas Tomcat desde eclipse, el IDE asume que si Tomcat no se ha lanzado en X segundos, es que hay un problema. El número de segundos por defecto es 45, pero si añades más de una aplicación a tu instancia de Tomcat o tienes una muy pesada, es fácil que pasen esos 45 segundos y eclipse mate el proceso.

La solución es simple (una vez que la conoces, claro): Aumentar el tiempo de espera (timeout), haciendo doble click en el servidor y modificando el campo **Start(in seconds)** de la pantalla que se te abra:

[image: captura de pantalla]